# Cucumber doesn't find Step Definition when passing a Java Enum type

Tags: java, cucumber

I followed the example in this README: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions#readme , but I must be doing something wrong. The scenario file doesn't find the method in the step definitions.

Line in scenario file:

```
And I disable identity provider with name "identity provider name"
```

Step definition and parametertype configuration in step definition file:

```
  @ParameterType("enable|disable")
  public State state(String name){
    return State.valueOf(name);
  }        

  @And("^I {state} identity provider with name \"([^\"]*)\"$")
  public void I_change_enabled_status_of_identity_provider_with_name(State state, final String idpName) {
         

      METHOD BODY


  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix up Cucumber expressions (`{state}` is a syntax of Cucumber expressions) and regular expressions (which are detected by Cucumber by locating leading `^` and trailing `$`).

So you have to make your choice. Whether to use Cucumber or Regular expressions.

**P.S.** - With Cucumber expression the following would work for you:

`@And("I {state} identity provider with name {string}")`